# What data structure do I need or how to implement a "LIFO-like" queue?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure that behaves like this:

1. Last in, first out
2. Upon iteration the first item is the item that was last in (LCFS - last come, first served)
3. When max capacity is reached, the 'oldest' item(s) need(s) to be dropped

It sounds like a `Queue` would do the trick, but that structure is FIFO. Sounds like I need a LIFO-like queue.

Any ideas what I should use?

Comment: What you describe looks more like a stack than a queue...

Comment: Are you looking for a Stack?  Though the standard .NET Stack doesn't discard old items.

Comment: you can use stack which fulfill your requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in base .NET library, but that doesn't have the last requirement. And I believe there is no existing structure like that, so you have to implement it yourself.

But that shouldn't be a problem. Just create a linked list where you add and remove from one side and remove from other when number of items exceeds given size. You could optimize it by using an array with begin-end pointers, but then you would have to periodically re-arrange the array so you don't run out of space. The cyclic version could actually work better than rearanging.

I did some quick hacking with the cyclic version. I'm sure you can add the interfaces yourself.

```
public class DroppingStack<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T[] array;
    int cap;
    int begin;
    int end;
    public DroppingStack (int capacity)
    {
        cap = capacity+1;
        array = new T[cap];
        begin = 0;
        end = 0;
    }

    public T pop()
    {
        if (begin == end) throw new Exception("No item");
        begin--;
        if (begin < 0)
            begin += cap;
        return array[begin];
    }

    public void push(T value)
    {
        array[begin] = value;
        begin = (begin+1)%cap;
        if (begin == end)
            end = (end + 1) % cap;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int i = begin-1;
        while (i != end-1)
        {
            yield return array[i];
            i--;
            if (i < 0)
                i += cap;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does a stack have an iterator?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker, yes it does, and it enumerates in the order you specified (LCFS)

Comment: Wow.. magic :). The only thing I need as well is an capacity increase :P

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker capacity increase? Like increasing capacity after the stack is created while keeping the items? Yeah, that might be slightly harder.

Comment: @Euphoric in your GetEnumerator(), if/when begin == 0, won't i == -1, and cause an error when trying to index 'array' at -1?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`LinkedList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netcore-3.1):

```
public class LifoBuffer<T> : LinkedList<T>
{
    private int capacity;

    public LifoBuffer(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;   
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (Count == capacity) RemoveLast();
        AddFirst(item);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var lifoBuffer = new LifoBuffer<int>(3);
    lifoBuffer.Add(1);
    lifoBuffer.Add(2);
    lifoBuffer.Add(3);
    lifoBuffer.Add(4);
    lifoBuffer.Add(5);
    foreach (var item in lifoBuffer) Console.WriteLine(item); // outputs: 5, 4, 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's like an cyclic LIFO with defined capacity.

Comment: Do we have structures available or would I have to make my own?

Answer (score 1):

.Net has a LIFO "queue" structure called [`Stack<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), although this does not fulfill your third constraint (e.g. size constrained). It wouldn't be too difficult to achieve this by means of containment.

However... if you want to throw away the oldest items in your stack, it might be better to use a circular buffer. This might be implemented as follows:

```
class OverflowingStack<T>
{
    private T[] items;
    private int currentIndex;
    private int count;

    public OverflowingStack(int size)
    {
        this.items = new T[size];
        this.currentIndex = 0;
        this.count = 0;
    }
    public void Push(T item)
    {
        items[currentIndex] = item;
        currentIndex++;
        currentIndex %= items.Length;
        count++;
        count = count > items.Length ? items.Length : count;

    }
    public T Pop()
    {
        if (count == 0) throw new Exception("stack is empty");
        currentIndex--;
        while (currentIndex < 0) {currentIndex += items.Length;}
        count--;
        return items[currentIndex];
    }
}
```

I'll leave the additional interface implementations to you, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, but that's not enough... it doesn't handle the last requirement (dropping old items)

Comment: Does this fulfill the third requirement? Is a link-only answer acceptable on SO?

Comment: Ok, it doesn't fulfill point 3, but I'm sure it presents a handy bit of information to OP that a LIFO "queue" is called a *Stack*.

Comment: @spender: There are other people who also thought that this is useful information. They left comments.

Comment: Hm... looks good... but it stops pushing its when the stack is "full"... bit should remove the "bottom" items when it is "full".

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker Hmmm... I'm starting to think a circular buffer might suit your situation better.

Comment: What is a circular buffer?

Comment: Yeah looks more like the thing I need

Answer (score 1):

Well the exemplary last in, first out data structure is a [`Stack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will fulfill both the first and second requirement. However, this does not fulfill the third requirement. For that requirement you'd probably be best of using a `Queue`, although that is by default a FIFO data type. I don't believe there is an existing data structure that matches your requirements, which means you'd have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, feel free to use it. Implementation of IEnumerable is an exercise for the reader (if he needs it):

```
    class CyclicStack<T>
    {
        private T[] stack;
        private int capacity;
        private int curIndex = 0;

        public  int Count { get; private set; }
        public CyclicStack(int capacity)
        {
            this.capacity = capacity;
            stack = new T[capacity];
            this.Count = 0;
        }
        public T this[int index]
        {
           get
           {
               if (index >= capacity)
                   throw new Exception("Index is out of bounds");
               return this.stack[(curIndex + index) % capacity];
           }
        }
        public void Push(T item)
        {
            curIndex = (curIndex + capacity - 1) % capacity;
            stack[curIndex] = item;
            this.Count++;
        }
        public T Pop()
        {
            if (this.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("Collection is empty");
            int oldIndex = curIndex;
            curIndex = (curIndex + capacity + 1) % capacity;
            this.Count--;
            return stack[oldIndex];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the `Stack` class

[MSDN Stack Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.stack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)